# dotenv not loading .env file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using the dotenv library, I am unable to access the process.env variables from my node project.

index.js(entry point)

```
const result = require('dotenv').config()
if (result.error) {
  throw result.error
}
console.log(result.parsed)
console.log(process.env.JIRA_CONSUMER_KEY);
```

.env

```
JIRA_CONSUMER_KEY:bot-consumer-key
```

command line output

```
⇒  nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 1.12.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
{}
undefined
undefined
```

file tree

```
- icm_bot
    - index.js
    - .env
```

Answer (score 6):

It's equals not colon in the .env file!

```
JIRA_CONSUMER_KEY=bot-consumer-key
```

Otherwise you get no dictionary!

Comment: @Wuzza it would be nice to give Robert, the correct answer check :)